# MFC CString to int

Tags: windows, mfc, atoi

using this code i get an error at `atoi`'s conversion from `CString` to `int`:

```
    int nrCentrala; CString idCentrala;
    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_IDCENTRALA)->GetWindowText(idCentrala);
    nrCentrala = atoi(&idCentrala);
```

where `IDC_EDIT_IDCENTRALA` is an edit control.

`Error  7   error C2664: 'atoi' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CString *' to 'const char *'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass pointer to `CString` (`CString*` type) instead of `const char*` which is expected by `atoi()`. Correct call is `nrCentrala = atoi(idCentrala.GetString());`

Comment: Remove &, you don't need it. Operator & means "get pointer to object", you don't need to pass pointer to CString to atoi(), you need to pass const char* which is returned by CString::GetString()

Comment: i did that, i got another one `Error 7 error C2664: 'atoi' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t *' to 'const char *'`

Comment: Looks like you have `UNICODE` defined, so `CString` is actually `CStringW`. Try to replace `atoi` with `_wtoi` or `_tstoi`

Answer (score 6):

CString provides an overloaded operator for LPCTSTR. Also, use _tstoi instead, just in case you're compiling with Unicode libraries, e.g.

```
nrCentrala = _tstoi(idCentrala);
```